# New version of firefox breaks my threejs scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene in threejs that worked perfectly in Firefox two weeks ago.  Today, after updating Firefox recently, I opened up the exact same file, and now I see a very brief flash of the image and then I get a completely blank, white page.  It's all local code, relying on a local, downloaded version of three.min.js, so I'm positive there have been no changes to the files.

The examples on the three.js website work fine, so I don't know why my local files would be misbehaving in the latest version of Firefox.

Does anyone know of any changes recently to Firefox that interact poorly with three.js?  How to fix it?

[Working fine in Internet Explorer 11.  In Chrome, scene appears, but the textured cubes are missing or invisible.]

Comment: Open your javascript console (F12 on windows). Any errors?

Comment: I see the same warnings I saw when I ran a couple weeks ago and everything worked: 
"THREE.WebGLRenderer" "70" three.min.js:513:51
"THREE.PlaneGeometry: Consider using THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry for lower memory footprint." three.min.js:732:38
"THREE.CubeGeometry has been renamed to THREE.BoxGeometry." three.min.js:711:41
"THREE.PlaneGeometry: Consider using THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry for lower memory footprint."